# Problemas con la validación de un Form en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy teniendo un problemas [Este sitio](http://www.morpheuslights.com/prueba/welivery_web/?) con el Form no me muestra el mensaje de envió debajo del boton.

La idea es que cuando no se completen los campos y des en enviar aparezca un mensaje y cuando este completo y envíes el form aparezca otro.

Arme el siguiente codigo:

```js
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){
  
  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");

  var hasError = false;
  var hasvalid = true;
  
  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasError = true;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }
    
    }); //Input

  validMessage.slideDown(700);

  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasvalid = false;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      validMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }
    
    }); //Input
  
  validMessage.slideDown(700);

    /*ajax*/
  if(hasError == false){
      Ecommerce = document.getElementById("exampleInputEcommerce").value;
      Nombre = document.getElementById("exampleInputNombre").value;
      Telefono = document.getElementById("exampleInputPhone").value;
      Email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value; 
      data2= { 
          ecommerce:Ecommerce,
          nombre:Nombre,
          telefono:Telefono,
          email:Email,
          tarea: "envio"
        };
      
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"envio.php",
        data: data2,
        success:function(data){
          console.log("entro");
          /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );*/
          
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );
          $(".inputValidation").val("");
        } 
        
      });

  }




}); //Form .submit
```

```css
.info-section .inputError {
  background-color: #9e46578c!important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #824747!important;
  color: #fff;
}

.info-section .inputError::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

.info-section .errorMessage {
  /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
  color: #fff;
  clear: right;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.info-section .validMessage {
  /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
  color: #fff;
  clear: right;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.info-section .errorMessage p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.info-section .validMessage {
  /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
  color: #fff;
  clear: right;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.info-section .validMessage p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<form class="formValidation px-lg-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEcommerce" aria-describedby="Ecommerce" placeholder="Ecommerce">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputNombre" aria-describedby="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="phone" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputPhone" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-5">
    <input type="email" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn_enviar_form mt-sm-5">ENVIAR</button>

</form>

<div class="errorMessage"></div>

<div class="validMessage" id="respuesta"></div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo modifica tu HTML, ya que estás mandando llamar el jquery 2 junto con el jquery slim.
Correctamente quedaría así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<form class="formValidation px-lg-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEcommerce" aria-describedby="Ecommerce" placeholder="Ecommerce">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputNombre" aria-describedby="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="phone" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputPhone" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-5">
    <input type="email" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn_enviar_form mt-sm-5">ENVIAR</button>

</form>

<div class="errorMessage"></div>

<div class="validMessage" id="respuesta"></div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Pero vos ahi acomodaste algo del codigo? si vi que habia console log que estaba demas.

Comment: Solo agregué e function y el console.log(), soy nuevo usando loas respuestas de stackoverflow :D

Comment: Ahh esta, si ahí probé pero me sigue pasando lo mismo :(

Comment: Lo que no se si la funcion JS la estoy armando bien la idea es que cuando no se completen los campos aparezca un mensaje y cuando este completo y envien aparezca otro.

Comment: Trata encerrando la variable así  $(validMessage).slideDown(700);

Comment: Te agregué el HTML correcto :)

Comment: Mira aca actualice pero no me salio :( http://www.morpheuslights.com/prueba/welivery_web/

Comment: ahi edite el js

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){ $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){

  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");

  var hasError = false;
  var hasvalid = true;

  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasError = true;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }

    }); //Input
 

  validMessage.slideDown(700);

  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasvalid = false;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      validMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }

    }); //Input
  validMessage.slideDown(700);

    /*ajax*/
  if(hasError == false){
      Ecommerce = document.getElementById("exampleInputEcommerce").value;
      Nombre = document.getElementById("exampleInputNombre").value;
      Telefono = document.getElementById("exampleInputPhone").value;
      Email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value; 
      data2= { 
          ecommerce:Ecommerce,
          nombre:Nombre,
          telefono:Telefono,
          email:Email,
          tarea: "envio"
        };

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"envio.php",
        data: data2,
        success:function(data){
          console.log("entro");
          /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );*/

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );
          $(".inputValidation").val("");
        } 

      });

  }




}); //Form .submit
});
```